# Using jsdoc3 to document a module and submodule

Tags: javascript, module, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I have a module that follows this pattern.

```
/**
 *  @name Filters
 *  @namespace
 */
var Filters = (function (Filters, $) {
    Filters.switchView = function (newView) {
        // do something
    };
    return Filters;
})(Filters || {}, jQuery);
```

I then have a submodule for the Filters module

```
Filters.validator = (function (Filters, $) {
    var validator = {};
    validator.toggleErrorState = function (state, el) {
         // do something
    } 
    return validator;
})(Filters || {}, jQuery);
```

I can't figure out how to document the submodule. I've done some searches and haven't found anyone else that follows this particular pattern that is documenting with jsdoc style comments. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This documents both namespaces. First file:

```
/**
 *  @namespace
 */
var Filters = (function (Filters, $) {
    /**
     * switchView does...
     * @param newView The new view.
     */
    Filters.switchView = function (newView) {
        // do something
    };
    return Filters;
})(Filters || {}, jQuery);
```

Second file:

```
/**
 * @namespace
 */
Filters.validator = (function (Filters, $) {
    var validator = {};
    /**
     * toggleErrorState does...
     * @param state The state.
     * @param el The el.
     */
    validator.toggleErrorState = function (state, el) {
         // do something
    }
    return validator;
})(Filters || {}, jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 *  @namespace Parent
 */
var Filters = (function (Filters, $) {
    /**
     * switchView does...
     * @param newView The new view.
     */
    Filters.switchView = function (newView) {
        // do something
    };
    return Filters;
})(Filters || {}, jQuery);

/**
 * @namespace Child
 * @memberOf Parent
 */
Filters.validator = (function (Filters, $) {
    var validator = {};
    /**
     * toggleErrorState does...
     * @param state The state.
     * @param el The el.
     */
    validator.toggleErrorState = function (state, el) {
         // do something
    }
    return validator;
})(Filters || {}, jQuery);
```